# Memory quota exceeded in my heroku deployed rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My app has been working fine but today it is showing an error (www.guidelinesforme.com)

When I run heroku logs I get:

```
2013-07-16T10:32:11.738568+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2013-07-16T10:32:11.738306+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=514M(100.5%)
```

If someone can help me sort this out this I will be delighted.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16009865/477878) may help.

Comment: nice one!  Sorted it - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The RAM of your dyno has gone out of the higher bound, which is 512MB, as @JoachimIsaksson said you could monitor the memory usage with

```
heroku labs:enable log-runtime-metrics
```

I would suggest you to run a

```
heroku ps:restart
```

maybe that will solve the issue temporarily but at least you'll have a working site while you search for the cause of your memory problem.

Answer (score 0):

For any future searchers: If you're repeatedly getting this error on a Heroku-hosted Rails app, it's possible you're using the wrong webserver or have too many webserver workers for your instance size. For example, it looks like Unicorn is a better choice on Heroku than Puma. See this answer for more details: [Rails 4 Error R14 on Heroku (Memory Quota Exceeded)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23858694/rails-4-error-r14-on-heroku-memory-quota-exceeded)