# What is the formula for setting WEB_CONCURRENCY on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory-management, heroku, concurrency

I am frequently getting this error `Memory quota exceeded` for my `ruby on rails` application hosted on heroku:

```
2014-12-29 11:09:37.876 355 <45>1 2014-12-29T11:09:37.210533+00:00 heroku worker.1 - - source=worker.1 dyno=heroku.22144543.00c11b4d-8ec6-46d9-addf-f03163e10f0c sample#memory_total=2899.25MB sample#memory_rss=1023.73MB sample#memory_cache=0.00MB sample#memory_swap=1875.52MB sample#memory_pgpgin=2603236pages sample#memory_pgpgout=2341160pages
2014-12-29 11:09:37.876 132 <4
2014-12-29 11:09:37.876 132 <455>1 2014-12-29T11:09:37.210533+00:00 heroku worker.1 - - Process running mem=2899M(283.1%)>1 2014-12-29T11:09:37.210533+00:00 heroku worker.1 - - Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

I read the blog of which suggests the [solution](http://heridev.com.mx/ruby/how-i-solvedfixed-the-r14-error-in-heroku-com-in-a-spreerails-application/)  i.e. set `WEB_CONCURRENCY` config variable but it is not clear to me.

My current configuration on heroku are:

[image]

## config/unicorn.rb

```
worker_processes Integer(ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] || 3)
timeout 29
preload_app true
```

**Edited:**

Worker Code

```
class PhotoWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: "high"
  # sidekiq_options retry: false

  def perform(params)    
    begin
      puts "Start Woker for #{params.inspect}"
      site = Site.find params['site_id']      
      if params["id"].present?
        photo = Photo.find(params["id"])
        if params['key'].present?
          photo.key = params['key']
          photo.remote_image_url = photo.image.direct_fog_url(:with_path => true)
          photo.image_name = params['key'].split('/').last
          photo.save(validate: false)
          puts photo.inspect
        end     
      else     
        #photo = site.photos.build 
        #photo.hotel_detail_id = site.hotel_detail.id
        #photo.album_id = site.hotel_detail.album.id
        #photo.save(validate: false)
        photo.key = params['key']
        photo.remote_image_url = photo.image.direct_fog_url(:with_path => true)
        #photo.image = params['key']
        #photo.remote_image_url = params['key']
        photo.image_name = params['key'].split('/').last
        puts photo.inspect
        photo.save(validate: false)
      end

      if params["id"].present? && params["crop_x"].present? 
        photo.crop_x = params["crop_x"]
        photo.crop_y = params["crop_y"]
        photo.crop_w = params["crop_w"]
        photo.crop_h = params["crop_h"]
        photo.save(validate: false)
      end


      if params["id"].present? 
        if params['key'].present?
          s3 = AWS::S3.new.buckets[ENV["FOG_DIRECTORY"]]
          s3.objects[params['key']].delete
        end
      else
        AmazonFile.new(params['key']).delete
      end

      puts "Deleted temp file: #{params['key']}" if params['key'].present?
      puts "Photo(#{photo.id}) saved successfully. URL: #{params['key']}"
    rescue Exception => exc
      #puts "Photo not saved. URL: #{params['key']}" 
      puts "Error:  #{exc.message}"
    end      
  end

end
```

Apart from sidekiq i am also using `carrierwave_backgrounder` gem.

I am using Kraken for image compression

Photo Uploader

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base 
  #include ::CarrierWave::Backgrounder::Delay
  include CarrierWaveDirect::Uploader
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
  process :set_content_type
  process :crop  
  storage :fog
  after :store, :kraken

  version :admin do
    process :resize_to_fit => [200,200]
  end

  #Leisure theme
  version :leisure_358x243, :if => :leisure_theme? do
    process :resize_to_fill => [358,243]
  end
  version :leisure_900x500, :if => :leisure_theme? do
    process :resize_to_fill => [900,500]
  end
 version :leisure_350x147, :if => :leisure_theme? do
    process :resize_to_fill => [350,147]
  end
  version :leisure_1100x344, :if => :leisure_theme? do
    process :resize_to_fill => [1100,344]
  end

  #Business theme
  version :business_360x160, :if => :business_theme? do
    process :resize_to_fill => [360,160]
  end
  version :business_1100x315, :if => :business_theme? do
    process :resize_to_fill => [1100,315]
  end
  version :business_1140x530, :if => :business_theme? do
    process :resize_to_fill => [1140,530]
  end
  version :business_1100x355, :if => :business_theme? do
    process :resize_to_fill => [1100,355]
  end

  #Commthree theme
  version :commthree_550x300, :if => :commthree_theme? do
    process :resize_to_fill => [550,300]
  end
  version :commthree_319x183, :if => :commthree_theme? do
    process :resize_to_fill => [319,183]
  end
  version :commthree_1920x700, :if => :commthree_theme? do
    process :resize_to_fill => [1920,700]
  end

  #All theme
  version :all_360x188 do
    process :resize_to_fill => [360,188]
  end
  version :all_1100x401 do
    process :resize_to_fill => [1100,401]
  end
  version :all_140x88 do    
    process :resize_to_fill => [140,88]
  end

  def kraken(file)
    if version_name.to_s == ""      
      storepath = store_dir + "/" + filename
    else
      fname = filename.split('.')
      #originalfile = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/" + ENV["FOG_DIRECTORY"] + "/" + store_dir  + "/" + fname[0] + "_" + version_name.to_s + "." + fname.last
      storepath = store_dir + "/" + fname[0] + "_" + version_name.to_s + "." + fname.last
    end

    originalfile = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/" + ENV["FOG_DIRECTORY"] + "/" + store_dir + "/" + filename

    kraken = Kraken::API.new(
        :api_key => ENV['KRAKEN_API'],
        :api_secret => ENV['KRAKEN_SECRET']
    )

    params = {}


    Rails.logger.info('Kraken About to Process: ' + originalfile);
    p "version #{version_name}"
    case version_name.to_s
      when "admin"
        params = {
                'lossy' => true,
                'resize' => {
                     'width' => 200,
                     'height' => 200,
                    'strategy' => "auto",
                },
                's3_store' => {
                              'key' => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                              'secret' => ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],
                              'bucket' => ENV["FOG_DIRECTORY"],
                              'acl' => 'public_read',
                              'path' => storepath
                              },
                  }

      when "leisure_358x243"
        params = {
                'lossy' => true,
                'resize' => {
                    'width' => 358,
                    'height' => 243,
                    'strategy' => "fit",
                },
                's3_store' => {
                              'key' => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                              'secret' => ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],
                              'bucket' => ENV["FOG_DIRECTORY"],
                              'acl' => 'public_read',
                              'path' => storepath
                              },
                  }
      when "leisure_900x500"
        params = {
                'lossy' => true,
                'resize' => {
                    'width' => 900,
                    'height' => 500,
                    'strategy' => "fit",
                },
                's3_store' => {
                              'key' => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                              'secret' => ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],
                              'bucket' => ENV["FOG_DIRECTORY"],
                              'acl' => 'public_read',
                              'path' => storepath
                              },
                  }           
      when "leisure_350x147"
        params = {
                'lossy' => true,
                'resize' => {
                    'width' => 350,
                    'height' => 147,
                    'strategy' => "exact",
                },
                's3_store' => {
                              'key' => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                              'secret' => ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],
                              'bucket' => ENV["FOG_DIRECTORY"],
                              'acl' => 'public_read',
                              'path' => storepath
                              },
                  }
      when "leisure_1100x344"
        params = {
                'lossy' => true,
                'resize' => {
                    'width' => 1100,
                    'height' => 344,
                    'strategy' => "fit",
                },
                's3_store' => {
                              'key' => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                              'secret' => ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],
                              'bucket' => ENV["FOG_DIRECTORY"],
                              'acl' => 'public_read',
                              'path' => storepath
                              },
                  }

      when "business_360x160"
        params = {
                'lossy' => true,
                'resize' => {
                    'width' => 360,
                    'height' => 160,
                    'strategy' => "fit",
                },
                's3_store' => {
                              'key' => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                              'secret' => ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],
                              'bucket' => ENV["FOG_DIRECTORY"],
                              'acl' => 'public_read',
                              'path' => storepath
                              },
                  }                
      when "business_1100x315"
        params = {
                'lossy' => true,
                'resize' => {
                    'width' => 1100,
                    'height' => 315,
                    'strategy' => "fit",
                },
                's3_store' => {
                              'key' => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                              'secret' => ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],
                              'bucket' => ENV["FOG_DIRECTORY"],
                              'acl' => 'public_read',
                              'path' => storepath
                              },
                  }                
      when "business_1140x530"
        params = {
                'lossy' => true,
                'resize' => {
                    'width' => 1140,
                    'height' => 530,
                    'strategy' => "fit",
                },
                's3_store' => {
                              'key' => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                              'secret' => ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],
                              'bucket' => ENV["FOG_DIRECTORY"],
                              'acl' => 'public_read',
                              'path' => storepath
                              },
                  }
      when "business_1100x355"
        params = {
                'lossy' => true,
                'resize' => {
                    'width' => 1100,
                    'height' => 355,
                    'strategy' => "fit",
                },
                's3_store' => {
                              'key' => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                              'secret' => ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],
                              'bucket' => ENV["FOG_DIRECTORY"],
                              'acl' => 'public_read',
                              'path' => storepath
                              },
                  }

      when "commthree_550x300"
        params = {
                'lossy' => true,
                'resize' => {
                    'width' => 550,
                    'height' => 300,
                    'strategy' => "fit",
                },
                's3_store' => {
                              'key' => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                              'secret' => ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],
                              'bucket' => ENV["FOG_DIRECTORY"],
                              'acl' => 'public_read',
                              'path' => storepath
                              },
                  }
      when "commthree_319x183"
        params = {
                'lossy' => true,
                'resize' => {
                    'width' => 319,
                    'height' => 183,
                    'strategy' => "fit",
                },
                's3_store' => {
                              'key' => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                              'secret' => ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],
                              'bucket' => ENV["FOG_DIRECTORY"],
                              'acl' => 'public_read',
                              'path' => storepath
                              },
                  }
      when "commthree_1920x700"
        params = {
                'lossy' => true,
                'resize' => {
                    'width' => 1920,
                    'height' => 700,
                    'strategy' => "fit",
                },
                's3_store' => {
                              'key' => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                              'secret' => ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],
                              'bucket' => ENV["FOG_DIRECTORY"],
                              'acl' => 'public_read',
                              'path' => storepath
                              },
                  }

      when "all_360x188"
        params = {
                'lossy' => true,
                'resize' => {
                    'width' => 360,
                    'height' => 188,
                    'strategy' => "fit",
                },
                's3_store' => {
                              'key' => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                              'secret' => ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],
                              'bucket' => ENV["FOG_DIRECTORY"],
                              'acl' => 'public_read',
                              'path' => storepath
                              },
                  }
      when "all_1100x401"
        params = {
                'lossy' => true,
                'resize' => {
                    'width' => 1100,
                    'height' => 401,
                    'strategy' => "fit",
                },
                's3_store' => {
                              'key' => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                              'secret' => ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],
                              'bucket' => ENV["FOG_DIRECTORY"],
                              'acl' => 'public_read',
                              'path' => storepath
                              },
                  }
      when "all_140x88"
        params = {
                'lossy' => true,
                'resize' => {
                    'width' => 140,
                    'height' => 88,
                    'strategy' => "fit",
                },
                's3_store' => {
                              'key' => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                              'secret' => ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],
                              'bucket' => ENV["FOG_DIRECTORY"],
                              'acl' => 'public_read',
                              'path' => storepath
                              },
                  }
    end


    #Store the file online

    if !version_name.blank?

      Rails.logger.info('UPLOADING TO: ' + store_path);

      data = kraken.url(originalfile,params)

      if data.success
          Rails.logger.info('KRAKEN: Success! Optimized image URL: ' + data.kraked_url)
      else
          puts 
          Rails.logger.info('KRAKEN: Fail. Error message: ' + data.message)
      end

    end    
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  # def cache_dir    
  #   "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
  # end

  def store_dir
    if model.id.present?
      "photos/#{model.id}"
    else
      "photos"
    end
  end

  #file name is missing extension!!!
  def filename
    original_filename if original_filename.present?
  end

  def crop
     puts "i am uploader"
    if model.crop_x.present?
      manipulate! do |img|
        puts "i am cropping"
        cx = model.crop_x.to_i
        cy = model.crop_y.to_i
        cw = model.crop_w.to_i
        ch = model.crop_h.to_i        
        img.crop"#{cw}x#{ch}+#{cx}+#{cy}"
        #img
      end
    end
  end

  def business_theme? (image)
    p "model:#{model.id}"
    (model.hotel_detail.site.theme.layout == "x1")if model.id.present?
  end

  def leisure_theme? (image)
    p "model:#{model.id}"
    (model.hotel_detail.site.theme.layout == "x2")if model.id.present?
  end

  def commthree_theme? (image)
    p "model:#{model.id}"
    (model.hotel_detail.site.theme.layout == "x3") if model.id.present?
  end

  protected
  def secure_token(length=16)
    var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
    model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, SecureRandom.hex(length/2))
  end

end
```

Please suggest me how to calculate the correct value of `WEB_CONCURRENCY`.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#r14-memory-quota-exceeded   and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23858694/rails-4-error-r14-on-heroku-memory-quota-exceeded may be this will help you

Comment: @RajarshiDas thanks, could you write a precise and clear answer to my problem?

Comment: Do you know how much memory your app needs on average? Do you use New Relic?

Comment: The error you are getting refers to memory being used on the worker/Sidekiq dyno (hence not related to web/Unicorn). You only have one 2X dyno enabled there, so you're limited to 1024MB (which is still plenty, but still to little since your job is currently using ~2900MB).

Comment: I'd suggest you tune your dyno setting more towards background processing (web -> worker) since thats where you're experiencing memory issues. If left as-is, you seem to need 3 worker dynos (3 X 1024MB). 

If you only use 3 unicorn worker processes, there's no reason to have 5 web dynos - the only thing you'll accomplish is spending your money on resources that wont be used.

Heroku has a good article on [Optimizing Dyno Usage](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/optimizing-dyno-usage) with a bunch of recommendations for appropriate WEB_CONCURRENCY settings. Good luck.

Comment: @spickermann yes i am using New Relic, i don't know to figure out average memory usage.

Comment: @simonnordberg thanks for comments, but could you write an answer pointing each thing that i need to do in code as well as settings, as i am not familiar with these type of detailed configuration.

Comment: @SachinSingh by the looks of things the only thing you need to do in order to get rid of memory warning is to change the worker dyno setting from 1 to 3 (hence increasing the available memory to 3*1024MB = 3072MB). So, no code change necessary for that, only Heroku configuration.

As a separate action I would also monitor the Rails application web memory usage (with New Relic) and set the web dyno and WEB_CONCURRENCY settings accordingly (with guidance from the Heroku documentation). This will only result in lowering your Heroku billing costs and has nothing to do with your original question.

Comment: @simonnordberg `worker_processes Integer(ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] || 3)` what does this mean?

Comment: @SachinSingh This sets the number of Unicorn workers to the environment variable WEB_CONCURRENCY (set via `heroku config:set`). If no value is set for the environment variable, a default of 3 will be used.

Comment: @spickermann here i have set it to 3, and image uploaded there i have specified 5 unicorn workers, it means i am not using 2 unicorn workers, right?

Comment: Can you post the code for your workers? I'm curious why they are so memory hungry. I think the solution you are looking for is more about performance turning your workers rather than tweaking dynos.

Comment: @eabraham see updated worker code.

Comment: Can you post the photo model too? Are you doing image manipulation?  (if so, its probably the cause of the high memory usage.)

Comment: @eabraham added photo uploader where image manipulation is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using both minimagick and kraken to do image manipulation.  If you fully migrate to Kraken and let them handle all of your image manipulation you shouldn't have a problem with memory on your workers.

Remove all of your versions and see if that improves performance.

```
version :leisure_358x243, :if => :leisure_theme? do
  process :resize_to_fill => [358,243]
end
```

If you want to stick with processing images on your workers there are more efficient libraries than carrierwave-minimagick. Take a look at [carrierwave-vips](https://github.com/eltiare/carrierwave-vips).

Comment: could you explain how to create image version with kraken?

Comment: At the bottom of the Photo Uploader file there is [Kraken](https://kraken.io/docs/getting-started) config code.  It looks like its all specified there.  Did you write it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "magic formula" - as per the [Heroku docs for Deploying Rails Applications on Unicorn - Caveats](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn#caveats):

> Each forked OS process consumes additional memory. This limits how
>   many processes you can run in a single dyno. With a typical Rails
>   memory footprint, you can expect to run 2-4 Unicorn worker processes.
>   Your application may allow for more or less processes depending on
>   your specific memory footprint, and we recommend specifying this
>   number in an config var to allow for faster application tuning.

Additionally, specific versions of Ruby run better on Heroku than others, due to memory leaks.  I strongly suggest Ruby 2.0.0 for the best memory maintenance with the New Relic gem, as the latest New Relic gem [has evidence of a memory leak](https://forum.upcase.com/t/how-to-free-up-swap-space-heroku/3017/7).  I personally had issues with the New Relic gem on Ruby 2.1.1, 2.1.3, and 2.1.4.  I've since downgraded to 2.0.0, which cut my memory usage in half.

However, if you're concerned about performance of Ruby 2.0.0, you might want to check out an alternative to New Relic, at least until New Relic patches the memory leak in their latest gem.

Comment: No, not really... There are a lot of variables that go into memory usage, such as number of objects instantiated by your app, how big those objects are, how long they stay in memory, etc.  That, combined with the known memory leak in Ruby 2.1, which is magnified by the New Relic gem... I don't know how it could ever be calculated.

Answer (score 1):

Just to react about CDub's answer. I had a couple of memory issues with the last Ruby version. Yes, New Relic seems to use a lot of memory but it's not the reason of those `Memory quota exceeded` errors.
After reading a lot of posts talking about that problem, it seems that the real cause come from the Ruby GC, which is causing a lot of server swapping since version 2.1.x .

To fix that I just set `RUBY_GC_HEAP_OLDOBJECT_LIMIT_FACTOR` to a value around `1.25`.
You can play with that setting to find the best value for your environment.

FYI my app is running with `Ruby 2.1.5` on Heroku `Cedar 14`

Hope it helps :)